# UI tests don't focus chrome

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, vstest

I run selenium UI tests on multiple servers via test runner task in TFS. 
Most of the tests are going fine and pass, and some of them fail because the chrome stays minimized and the test cannot start. I've tried to use screenshot of selenium in order to maximize the chrome and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are failing due to chrome staying minimized, may be you can try the window maximize method of webdriver as explained [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.maximize_window).

```
driver.maximize_window()
```